# CSS div block makes text disappear

Tags: html, css

I've got the following css file :

```
.h_bg{
    padding:22.4% 0;
    background-size:100% auto;
    background-position:center top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    height: 2em;
}
.h_bg h1{
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    line-height:1;
    top: 23%;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:500%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 15%;
    background-size:89px 183px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:1001px)
{
    .h_bg{
        background-image:url(/images/bg1-desktop.png);
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1001px) and (max-width:1300px)
{
    .h_bg h1{
        background-size:7% auto;
        padding-bottom: 16%;
    }
}
```

And the following html page :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
            <title>Beauty app</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="h_bg">
        <h1>text</h1>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

css link extactly to the place, where css file is. Unfortunately, text string is invisible and this code shows blank page. What can be a problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put it in a jsfiddle and ill take a look

Comment: h1 color is white, thats why you cant see h1 text

Comment: `.h_bg` class has `#fff` color. `#fff` is `white`. this may be the reason..

Comment: And maybe that background url is invalid so you cant see it.

Comment: very good explanation. Yep. What about absence of bg image? css file is in folder contains image folder. Should i add dot to the path?

Comment: Use inspect element and see is the background loaded or invalid url

Comment: If your css file is in css folder then yes you need to go one "level" out, so it should be like this `../images/bg1-desktop.png`, but if image folder is inside css folder then just do this `background-image:url("images/bg1-desktop.png");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is here:

```
color:#fff;
```

The #fff is forcing your H1 text in h_bg class to be white color, therefore it is invisible

Just incase you hit similar issues in future. This is how you can debug it.

Open your browser (i was using chrome) then right click on the element, for your instance its kind of difficult because you can't see it then click on inspect element.

On the bottom right corner you should see your CSS properties, try play around with it till you found your problem.

Comment: yep, that was the problem. In inspector i found, that the file with .png extension doesn't exist. Thanks for inspector. Very useful tool)